# What Java components do I need to use Clojure?

Tags: java, ubuntu, clojure

I'm setting up an Ubuntu VM to experiment with Clojure. In [the Getting Started guide for Clojure](http://clojure.org/getting_started), it shows running a `java` command. `which java` in my vm doesn't find anything.

I know nothing about Java. Tutorials for installing Java talk about the runtime environment, the SDK, etc.

What do I actually need in order to run Clojure?

Answer (score 3):

## Just the Runtime Environment

To run the REPL, all I needed was the Java Runtime Environment, which I installed with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`.